# String Mapping in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have implemented a Javascript Ajax search where if user types a city name I am populating the name in the search result. Problem is there are cities which have alternate names (for example Mumbai has Bombay as alternate name.....Bangalore has Bengaluru as alternate name). I want to map the alternate names of the city to the correct name using javascript. ALSO there might be multiple alternate names for the city not only one. so how can I map alternate cities name to correct one using javascript.

Comment: You could probably do a regex search... Or put the possible names into an array and compare against it?

Comment: var alternateCityNames = {Bangalore:bangaluru, Mumbai:bombay}   I am able to get the user entered string and able to compare against my array of alternate cities name, but I am not sure how do I replace the search string with the actual city string....I am sorry but I am not very clear about array

Comment: Show how do you obtain this string. Reverting to put it back will be pretty simple (though it have absolutely nothing to do with arrays/objects or string mapping at all).

Comment: @Kalish, in my example, the user input is stored in `var city`, in Oleg's, it's stored in `var userCity`, follow either answer and it will work. My answer shows a cool example of defaulting values using the `||` operator

Comment: thanks for suggestions, I will implement and let you all know...this forum is really worth exploring...so quick reply...thanks everryone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var alternates = {
    Bombay    : "Mumbai",
    Bengaluru : "Bangalore",
}

var userCity = obtainUserInputSomehow()
if (alternates.hasOwnProperty(userCity)) { userCity = alternates[userCity] }
// after this userCity will have "Mumbai" if user entered "Bombay" or "Mumbai".
// add as many aliases as you need.
```

Comment: thanks guys!!  both the answers (from Juan Mendes and Oleg V. Volkov are working) and I can select only one answer I am selecting Oleg V. Volkov's answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
var duplicateNameCities = {
    "Bengaluru": "Bangalore",
    "Mumbai": "Bombay"
};

// when you're given a string, run it through this map first
city = duplicateNameCities[city] || city;
```

However, it feels like the server side should handle this

Comment: ok, looks really helpful but when I get the string and I find that ok user has entered "Bengaluru" how do I replace that with the actual value(Bangalore) and pass it to server so that it returns the correct result.....sorry but I am very new to array

Comment: @Kalish, it's in the answer. If the city that was input is stored in `var city`, you just call `city = duplicateNameCities[city] || city;`

Comment: @Kalish: That's what the line `city = duplicateNameCities[city] || city;` is doing. Btw, there is no array in Juan's answers, `duplicateNameCities` is an *object*. If you are new to JavaScript I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).